# Update organization in already created flutter project

Tags: flutter

Say I've created a project like `flutter create --org com.myproject project`.

Is there a command to run to change the organization in the already created project in all the areas it is specified?

Thus perhaps a command with a different org changes all the org name in their respective places when called within the project.

`flutter update --org com.yourproject`

Comment: I doubt it. It cannot be sure where you have used the domain in your project. I would just update it manually if there is no answer here.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Updating manually, which files are my looking at to make the changes?

Comment: In Android Studio you might be able to replace every `com.yourproject` with Ctrl+Shift+R.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a way to do this. Instead you can do this manually by editing the following:-

### **`android/app/build.gradle`**

In `android { defaultConfig {} }` the property named `applicationId`

### All your `AndroidManifest.xml` files

Update `package` property in all your `AndroidManifest.xml` files, i.e. `/android/app/src/main`, `/android/app/src/debug`, `/android/app/src/profile`.

### Change directory name

If you see `/android/app/src/main/[kotlin or java]`, you will find nested directories `com` then `example` and then `[appName]` by default. It resembles the application ID so change the directory names.

### Modify `/android/app/src/main/[java or kotlin]/[by default com/example/[applicationName]]/[MainActivity.kt || MainActivity.java]`

In this file at the first some lines you will find your applicationID. Change it.

Then run `flutter clean && flutter run`.

Answer (score 2):

Installation:

`flutter pub global activate rename`

Note: Run the command inside your flutter project root.

```bash
rename setAppName --value "Dragon Notes"
rename setBundleId --value "com.dragon.notesapp"
```

To target a specific platform, use the "--targets" option. e.g.

```bash
rename setAppName --targets ios,android,macos,linux,web,windows --value "Dragon Notes"
rename setBundleId --targets ios,android --value "com.dragon.notesapp"
```

Source: https://pub.dev/packages/rename